# SQL Replace in join condition affect performance badly

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables in Teradata that I need to join.
In one of the tables I need to remove a string from the joined column.

When I used:

```
JOIN ON OReplace(A.id, '/','')= B.id
```

The query run for over ten minutes.

I tried to change different parts of the query. One of the attempts was to move the Replace into Select, like:

```
SELECT OReplace(A.id, '/','') as id_new
...
JOIN ON id_new= B.id
```

And this run few seconds!

From my point of view, this is the same script and even the Explain is totaly the same... Can someone explain me why is there such huge difference in performance? Thank you.

Regards, Robert

Comment: You would need to look at the query plan to understand the difference in performance.

Comment: I would not expect any difference, too. If Explain is exactly the same it might be due to Workload Management, i.e. query #1 was put in a queue and delayed. Do you have access to DBQL to check the actual execution?

Comment: from a personal experience OReplace is really really slow and gives issue with large dataset , I will suggest you to use Regexp_replace instead and it should solve your issue

Comment: Some sites have a very old protected-mode OREPLACE UDF in SYSLIB, and that can be very, very slow. But the Teradata-supplied TD_SYSFNLIB.OREPLACE should be at least as fast as REGEXP_REPLACE..